# Comparing Dates of list Java

Tags: java, date, arraylist

I would like some help. I have a difficulty on comparing dates inside a list. I would like to compare the date of  List

my problem is that I am trying to compare date of examsDate inside Exams

I thought to save the dates on arraylist examDates and for Each mark of student compare them.
and then find the maxDate and compare with it.

```
 for (Mark mark : student.getMarks()) {
            dates.add(mark.getExamsDate();
        }
   
 Date maxDate = dates.stream()
            .max(Date::compareTo)
            .get();

 for (Mark mark : student.getMarks()) {
     for(Date date: examDates){
         if(mark.getExamsDate().before(maxDate)
             || mark.getExamsDate().equals(maxDate)) {
                           doSomething
                         } 
                    }
                }
        }
```

In this way i compare to same dates so it it not a solution .Maybe i should use collections but i am not familiar with it.

My difficulty is to compare
if(mark.getExamsDate().after(mark.getPreviousExamsDate()) and i don't know how to find the previous date

In other words
I would like to find all dates sorted by date. If max date exists doSomething, else
find the second one biggest Date and doSomething()

Comment: 1) You haven't defined what "previous exam date" means. Previous in what way? Position in the list returned by `getMarks()`? Largest exam date prior to the current exam date? --- 2) What should result be for the first exam date be? --- 3) In the nested loop, what is the point of the inner `date` loop? You don't use `date` for anything. --- 4) When would `mark.getExamsDate().after(maxDate)` ever be true? Since max date is the largest exam date, no exam date will be larger, aka after, the max date. Code is not making sense.

Comment: Not answering your question, I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead if the time of day doesn’t matter use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Sorry getPreviousExamsDate() doesn't exists .would be better use for (int i; i< students.getMarks.size(); i ++) to 
find the i-1 date?

Comment: I would like to find all dates sorted by date. If max date exists doSomething, else
find the second one biggest Date and doSomething()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is need to find a list of *two* latest *distinct* exam dates and apply `doSomething` operation to related marks (that is, `doSomething` is a `Consumer<Mark>`).

This can be implemented like this:

```java
List<Date> twoLatestDates = marks
        .stream()
        .map(Mark::getExamsDate) // Stream<Date>
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Date::compareTo)) // sort in descending order
        .distinct() // remove duplicates
        .limit(2)   // keep 2 latest dates
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

marks.stream()
     .filter(m -> twoLatestDates.contains(m.getExamsDate()))
     .forEach(MyClass::doSomething);

/////
private static void doSomething(Mark mark) {
    System.out.println("doSomething: " + mark);
}
```

Another approach could be to group marks by exam date, collect the results into sorted map
`SortedMap<Date, List<Mark>>` and then get the values by appropriate dates and apply `doSomething`:

```java
marks.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             Mark::getExamsDate, // using examsDate as key
             TreeMap::new, // map sorted by examDate
             Collectors.toList()
     ))
     .descendingMap()   // reverse sorting order
     .values().stream() // Stream<List<Mark>>
     .limit(2)          // keep values related to the latest two dates
     .flatMap(List::stream) // join the streams into Stream<Mark>
     .forEach(MyClass::doSomething);
```